# Checking for an Acquia Environment variable

Tags: 8, theming

Trying to check for an Acquia cloud environment variable in my twig template, but its not working in Dev or in Production.

Similar question is answered here, but I still can't get the twig syntax right: [Is there a way to get (and use) an environment variable in my Twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253666/is-there-a-way-to-get-and-use-an-environment-variable-in-my-twig-template)

This is a snippet from the page.html.twig file.

```
{% if AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT == 'prod' %}
  // Javascript Analytics Code
{% else %}
  <!-- env is {{ AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT }} -->
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other question mentioned having passed that variable from a preprocess function to the template first. I guess that can be done using PHP's [`getenv`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.getenv.php) then. Let me just try that out.

Yep, that works.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_page().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['my_environment'] = getenv('AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT');
}
```

Then continue in `page.tpl.php`.

```
{% if my_environment == "prod" %}
  // Javascript Analytics Code
{% else %}
  <!-- env is {{ my_environment }} -->
{% endif %}
```